# Python, Pandas and intersection - not PIVOT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection

This isn't a  straightforward pivot question. I don't want to create new named columns (or numbered ones).

What I am looking for is to find a way to search for actors that satisfy the asked question, such as:

```
Any ACTOR that has UP and DOWN
```

in the table below.

| Actors | Events |
| --- | --- |
| A | Up |
| B | Up |
| C | Left |
| A | Down |
| D | Left |
| C | Down |
| C | Up |

The expected answer should be

```
[A,C]
```

So, using just event column to search for more than one event and returning the actor(s) that fulfill this requirement.

---

I have a set like this:

| Actors | Events |
| --- | --- |
| A | Up |
| B | Up |
| C | Left |
| A | Down |
| D | Left |
| C | Down |
| C | Up |

I want to find all actors that has events intersection.
Like:

```
Any ACTOR that has UP and DOWN
```

So this should return `A , C` and any other that has both.

One solution was to "explode" into new data frames by events, merge all by actors, creating a new data frame like:

| Actors | Event01 | Event02 | Event03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Up | Down |  |
| B | Up |  |  |
| C | Up | Down | Left |
| D |  |  | Left |

or even a dictionary with lists, like:

```
{'A':['Up', 'Down'], 'B': ... }
```

**But these solutions don't look very smart, thus consuming time, memory and process to explode and rebuild it.**

Plus, the big new DataFrame should have new columns with new names for events (not only one named **events**) which could be a little stressful to managing.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: `df.assign(col=df.groupby('Actors').cumcount()).pivot(index='Actors', columns='col', values='Events')`

Comment: Hi, @mozway.
Thanks for the reply. But, actually, I don't wanna pivot the table, 'cause this should give me named columns that will be hard to manage. I want to find a way to search into only one column and find all actors that satisfies the query.

Comment: Then your question is a bit too vague or off-topic. You should know which effect result you expect to ask a specific question. What's wrong with the original long format?

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I rewrote the question. What I am seeking is to return actors that have more than one queried events.
Eg.: actor(s) that have UP and DOWN event(s)
Following the presented table, the answer must be A and C actors.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `df.groupby('Actors')['Events'].nunique()`?

Comment: Hello, @mozway.
I believe the solution is something with 'groupby' but checking if the actors is subset of [Up, Down].
Some like a subset, not pivot.
The pivot code u passed gave mixed values columns (For the first column, the value is the first to appears - so if one actor has Up and the other Down, the first column should show UP and DOWN - mixed values). 
Still trying to find the solution for this Series. 
Thanks again, my friend. 
The pivot